# What happens to an animated object when it loses its creator?

Tags: dnd-5e, animated-objects

In the category "Animated Objects" on page 19, Monster's Manual says:

> When not commanded, they follow the last order they received to the best of
>   their ability, and can act independently to fulfill simple
>   instructions

It means if the creator dies after gave an order like "Protect this door" - or something like that - the Animated Object will accomplish the command until it dies too?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes, it will keep on carrying out its creator's final command.**

"Follow the last order they received" means exactly that.

Note that Animated Objects in the Monster Manual don't have any rules that requires their caster to be alive. Regular use of the *animate objects* spell, however, cannot create animated objects that stay animated after the caster dies — the spell requires concentration, and even then it normally ends after one minute.

Comment: Thank you! I know was dumb, but i wanted to be really sure!

Comment: @MarkusBendinho Just to make sure: I wasn't intending my answer to imply anything like that. I'll reword it if you feel it's too brusque or dismissive.

Comment: I don't know, SRD on Animated Objects doesn't talk about "Animated Objects Spell" on them, it says that are crafted with "potent magic" and I think it's like a different spell. Animated Objects on the Monster's Manual can also speak or even "converse fluently or adopt a persona".

Comment: Your answer was not too brusque or dismissive, don't worry!

Comment: @MarkusBendinho I have asked a few questions where the answer made me go back to the book and ask myself "uh, why didn't I see that before?"  You are in good company! :-)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It happens to me all the time!